# Cannot register new user on localhost ejabberd via Pidgin (503: service unavailable)

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I setted up ejabberd server on localhost and now can access admin panel on `localhost:5280/admin`

In pidgin I fill following values:

```
username: root
password: password
host: localhost
resource: 5280
```

and checking "Create this new account on the server"

There is my mod_register at `/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.cfg`

```
{mod_register, [
              %%
              %% After successful registration, the user receives
              %% a message with this subject and body.
              %%
              {welcome_message, {"Welcome!",
                                 "Welcome to a Jabber service powered by De$
                                 "For information about Jabber visit "
                                 "http://www.jabber.org"}},
              %% Replace it with 'none' if you don't want to send such mess$
              %%{welcome_message, none},

              %%
              %% When a user registers, send a notification to
              %% these Jabber accounts.
              %%
              %%{registration_watchers, ["admin1@example.org"]},
              {access, register, [{allow, all}]}
             ]},
```

When i try to register user pidgin says Error 503: Service unavailable

Where I wrong?

**UPD**

Pidgin logs:

```
(14:13:30) connection: Activating keepalive.
(14:13:31) jabber: Sending (ssl) (zuber@localhost/5280): <iq type='set' id='purple28d4cf' to='localhost'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'><username>zuber</username><password>123456</password></query></iq>
(14:13:31) jabber: Recv (ssl)(163): <iq from='localhost' id='purple28d4cf' type='error'><error code='503' type='cancel'><service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq>
(14:13:31) account: Disconnecting account zuber@localhost/5280 (0x7f06e57042b0)
(14:13:31) connection: Disconnecting connection 0x7f06e5606e30
(14:13:31) connection: Deactivating keepalive.
```

Ejabberd logs:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 2016-03-08 14:13:31 ===
E(<0.397.0>:ejabberd_hooks:335) : {{case_clause,
                                    {value,{access,register,[{allow,all}]}}},
                                   [{gen_mod,get_opt,3,
                                     [{file,"gen_mod.erl"},{line,154}]},
                                    {mod_register,process_iq,4,
                                     [{file,"mod_register.erl"},{line,109}]},
                                    {mod_register,
                                     unauthenticated_iq_register,4,
                                     [{file,"mod_register.erl"},{line,78}]},
                                    {ejabberd_hooks,run_fold1,4,
                                     [{file,"ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,331}]},
                                    {ejabberd_c2s,
                                     process_unauthenticated_stanza,2,
                                     [{file,"ejabberd_c2s.erl"},{line,2179}]},
                                    {ejabberd_c2s,wait_for_feature_request,2,
                                     [{file,"ejabberd_c2s.erl"},{line,731}]},
                                    {p1_fsm,handle_msg,10,
                                     [{file,"p1_fsm.erl"},{line,544}]},
                                    {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                     [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}
running hook: {c2s_unauthenticated_iq,
                  ["localhost",
                   {iq,"purple28d4cf",set,"jabber:iq:register",[],
                       {xmlelement,"query",
                           [{"xmlns","jabber:iq:register"}],
                           [{xmlelement,"username",[],
                                [{xmlcdata,<<"zuber">>}]},
                            {xmlelement,"password",[],
                                [{xmlcdata,<<"123456">>}]}]}},
                   {{127,0,0,1},57138}]}
```

Comment: What do your server logs say about the 503 error ?

Comment: where logs are storing?

Comment: I have no idea, you don't even say what OS you are using. Please, don't respond with the OS and expect us to tell you where the logs are, figure it out yourself.

Comment: Question updated. Logs are added to the end of post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I setted up ejabberd by other tutorial and all starts to work.

```
sudo apt-get install ejabberd
```

at /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.cfg:

1. uncomment line

   override_local
2. in `mod_register` config:

   %% Admin user
   {acl, admin, {user, "admin", "localhost"}}.

   %% Hostname
   {hosts, ["localhost"]}.
3. in `ACCESS RULES` section:

   {access, register, [{allow, all}]}.
4. restart server:

   sudo service ejabberd restart

Comment: There is no /etc/ejabberd directory

Comment: @Paul if you installed with apt-get package manager it creates /etc/ejabberd directory. If you installed with downloading deb file the config directory is /opt/ejabbed.conf.